# How to change Customer ID through Acumatica Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, acumatica

How do you change CustomerID through Acumatica Web Service I have this code but didn't work.

```
            LoginResult loginResult = context.Login("admin", "123");
            Content AR303000 = context.GetSchema();
            context.Clear();
            context.SetSchema(AR303000);
            var commands = new List<Command>();

            //AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerID.LinkedCommand = null;

            commands.Add(new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE", LinkedCommand = AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerID });
            commands.Add(AR303000.Actions.ChangeID);
            commands.Add(new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE1", LinkedCommand = AR303000.SpecifyNewID.CustomerID });
            commands.Add(new Value { Value = "OK", LinkedCommand = AR303000.SpecifyNewID.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer }); //---> I tried this line nothing works
            commands.Add(AR303000.Actions.Save);
            var result = context.Submit(commands.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'll try to provide a more detailed answer later but two quick tips: dialog answer and value has to be set before the dialog is displayed, and the dialog answer needs to be set on the primary view. There's another answer on StackOverflow that I answered which involves DialogAnswer and I show how to do it.

Comment: Ok tnx! I'm still trying to work it out though and I'm looking from other post here on stack overflow it might give me an idea.

Comment: I can't get it to work, it looks like there's a bug... still troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a slightly different order of commands, and set the Commit flag in a few places for it to work:

```
AR303000.Actions.ChangeID.Commit = true;
commands.Add(new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE", LinkedCommand = AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerID, Commit = true });
commands.Add(new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE1", LinkedCommand = AR303000.SpecifyNewID.CustomerID });
commands.Add(new Value { Value = "OK", LinkedCommand = AR303000.SpecifyNewID.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, Commit = true });
commands.Add(AR303000.Actions.ChangeID);
commands.Add(AR303000.Actions.Save);
```

I don't fully understand why the commit flag is needed on the ChangeID and the DialogAnswer commands, but this information comes straight from the creator of the Acumatica platform.